# Current state of integrating unit tests with Haskell's Cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck, hunit

When i google for how to integrate unit tests with cabal files, i either find

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program which does not seem to describe the integration of HUnit/QuickCheck with the Cabal file
- or i see messages like "wait for Cabal x.y which will support cabal test" but i can not find any documentation for this either

How would you run all unit test using cabal (for example everytime i do a "cabal build") today?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest version of Cabal and cabal-install installed.
2. Have a `test-suite` section in your `.cabal` file.  See [this section](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites) of cabal's documentation for an explanation of how to write a `test-suite` section in your Cabal file and [this section](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#setup-test) for instructions on how to run it.

I've been using the built-in test support for some time and it has saved me from having to maintain fragile Makefiles just for my tests. There are still some rough edges in the command line output of `cabal test`, but they have been fixed in HEAD so in the next Cabal/cabal-install release everything should be very smooth.

Comment: `cabal test` doesn't have test suite drivers for most frameworks yet, though... :(

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit unsure how HUnit and QuickCheck fit in there.

Comment: @Lenny222 They don't, yet. Use `defaultMainWithHooks` instead for the time being

Comment: Thanks guys. And how about "test-framework"? It would be really great if someone having a good overview over the current testing situation could find the time to write up a clarifying blog post or something.

Comment: I'll try to write a blog post soonish. The setup I use is to have a `test-suite` stanza of type `exitcode-stdio` and use test-framework (with its bindings to QC and HUnit) to write the actual test code. Look at: https://github.com/tibbe/hashable/blob/master/hashable.cabal and https://github.com/tibbe/hashable/blob/master/tests/Properties.hs