# QuickCheck exit status on failures, and cabal integration

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck

I'm trying to understand how to integrate some quickcheck tests with cabal. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/1343429) suggests that the `quickCheck` function returns non-zero status on failure, but I am not getting that behavior, so using cabal's `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test-suite type doesn't seem to work for me unless I want to call `error` all over my tests.

The cabal [user guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) also mentions a `detailed-1.0` test-suite, but AFAICT this doesn't exist yet. Is that still the case?

It seems from answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787231/current-state-of-integrating-unit-tests-with-haskells-cabal) that a lot of people are using the [test-framework package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-0.4.2.0). That's overkill for me, but is that what I should use?

I'm left kind of unsatisfied by this situation.

Versions of things I'm using:

```
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
QuickCheck-2.4.1.1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at [`quickCheck`'s implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/src/Test-QuickCheck-Test.html#quickCheck), it indeed never exits the program. However, you can easily implement this behaviour using [`quickCheckResult`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:quickCheckResult):

```
import Control.Monad
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Test
import System.Exit

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- quickCheckResult prop
  unless (isSuccess result) exitFailure
```

My understanding is that `detailed-1.0` is not considered ready for general use yet, and that `exitcode-stdio-1.0` is still the recommended testing solution for now.

Comment: I know it's been a 3+yrs, but I just spent way too much time trying to figure out that you also need to `import Test.QuickCheck.Test` for `isSuccess` to "be in scope". In case anyone is also having that problem.
On a side note, is there a way to make it nicer? (ie. not have to do both `import Test.QuickCheck` but also `Test.QuickCheck.Test`?)

Comment: @conrad It has apparently been ameliorated at some point: [isSuccess](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:isSuccess) is now in `Test.QuickCheck`.

Answer (score 6):

I used test-framework in the latest version of my [Decimal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal) package. It was not overkill; it did just what was wanted. Take a look at the [complete source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Decimal/0.2.2/Decimal-0.2.2.tar.gz) if you want an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I think I'll go that route