# Running “cabal test” passes although there are test failures

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal

I have a Cabal test target:

```
test-suite Tests
  type:              exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:           Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:    test, src
  build-depends:     base, …
  default-language:  Haskell2010
```

And a simple testing `Main.hs`:

```
import Test.HUnit
testSanity = TestCase $ assertEqual "Should fail" 2 1
main = runTestTT testSanity
```

Now running `cabal test` passes:

```
Test suite Tests: RUNNING...
Test suite Tests: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/Project-0.1.0-Tests.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

Even though there are failures correctly logged in the test suite log:

```
Test suite Tests: RUNNING...

Cases: 1  Tried: 0  Errors: 0  Failures: 0

### Failure:
Should fail
expected: 2
 but got: 1
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
Test suite Tests: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/Project-0.1.0-Tests.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`main` has to be of type `IO a` where `a` can be anything, and that value is not tied in any way to the POSIX exit status of the program.  You need to look at the `Counts` returned by `runTest` and explicitly choose a successful or failed output code.

```
import System.Exit

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cs@(Counts _ _ errs fails) <- runTestTT testSanity
    putStrLn (showCounts cs)
    if (errs > 0 || fails > 0) 
        then exitFailure
        else exitSuccess
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, but could you add some explanation for future readers?

Comment: Thanks! I guess it boils down to the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` “driver” specified in the Cabal file. It reports the result of the testing suite according to an exit code. Is there a simpler way to integrate the HUnit tests into Cabal without so  much boilerplate, maybe a specialized driver?

Comment: The developers of HUnit, like developers of basically every other Haskell library, see process termination as something outside the scope of HUnit.

Comment: @zoul [Tasty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty)'s [`defaultMain`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.0.3/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:defaultMain) (with [Tasty-hunit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit)) is exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `exitcode-stdio-1.0` expects the test to communicate failure via the program's exit code. However, if you run the test program manually from the shell (look in the `dist/build` directory) I think you'll find that the exit code is always 0.

Here is a related SO question which suggests that your test should call `exitFailure` if your suite doesn't pass:

[QuickCheck exit status on failures, and cabal integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976488/quickcheck-exit-status-on-failures-and-cabal-integration)

FWIW, it works correctly when using `stack`:

```
$ mkdir new-dir
$ cd new-dir
$ stack new
(edit new-template.cabal to add HUnit as a test dependency)
(add test case to test/Spec.hs)
$ stack test
```

Perhaps `stack` is also scanning the test output.