# I run "cabal test" with a failing case but it always passes

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal

I want to test a function and I want this test to fail. After initiating the project using `cabal init`, I created my `findOddInt` function in the `Main.hs` file in the `app` directory:

```
module Main where

findOddInt :: [Int] -> Int
findOddInt (x:xs) = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"
```

I created a directory named `tests` and created the `FindOddInt.hs` file:

```
module FindOddInt ( main ) where
import Main hiding ( main )
import Test.HUnit
import qualified System.Exit as Exit

test1 :: Test
test1 = TestCase (assertEqual "should return an odd integer" 3 (findOddInt [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]))

tests :: Test
tests = TestList [TestLabel "test1" test1]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- runTestTT tests
    if failures result > 0 then Exit.exitFailure else Exit.exitSuccess
```

my `.cabal` file is as follows:

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               find-odd-int
version:            0.1.0.0

-- A short (one-line) description of the package.
-- synopsis:

-- A longer description of the package.
-- description:

-- A URL where users can report bugs.
-- bug-reports:

-- The license under which the package is released.
-- license:
author:             André Ferreira
maintainer:         andresouzafe@gmail.com

-- A copyright notice.
-- copyright:
-- category:
extra-source-files: CHANGELOG.md

executable find-odd-int
    main-is:          Main.hs

    -- Modules included in this executable, other than Main.
    -- other-modules:

    -- LANGUAGE extensions used by modules in this package.
    -- other-extensions:
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.3.0
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite tests
    type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is: FindOddIntTest.hs
    build-depends: base ^>=4.14, HUnit ^>=1.6
    hs-source-dirs: app, tests
    other-modules: Main
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

All set, I ran `cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal test` and got the output:

```
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.7 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - find-odd-int-0.1.0.0 (test:tests) (file app/Main.hs changed)
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for find-odd-int-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'tests' for find-odd-int-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, /home/asf/Projects/codewars-exercises/haskell/6-kyu/find-odd-int/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0/t/tests/build/tests/tests-tmp/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling FindOddInt       ( tests/FindOddIntTest.hs, /home/asf/Projects/codewars-exercises/haskell/6-kyu/find-odd-int/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0/t/tests/build/tests/tests-tmp/FindOddInt.o ) [Main changed]
Linking /home/asf/Projects/codewars-exercises/haskell/6-kyu/find-odd-int/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0/t/tests/build/tests/tests ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
Test suite tests: PASS
Test suite logged to:
/home/asf/Projects/codewars-exercises/haskell/6-kyu/find-odd-int/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0/t/tests/test/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0-tests.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

I already looked the following posts:

- [Running “cabal test” passes although there are test failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492666/running-cabal-test-passes-although-there-are-test-failures)
- [Create and run a minimal test suite in Haskell using Hunit only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334745/create-and-run-a-minimal-test-suite-in-haskell-using-hunit-only)

These posts don't cover my case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in `FindOddIntTest.hs`, the file your cabal file claims is your test suite?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use just plain HUnit? I'd recommend something like [tasty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty): it's more flexible and gives you clear information regarding what tests are actually being run. (But, of course it also shouldn't be too difficult to get it working with plain HUnit!)

Comment: @amalloy what did you mean?

Comment: Your file is named `FindOddIntTest.hs` but inside it says `main FindOddInt where`, which is confusing (and partially related to the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included the source of your executable as part of your test suite (`hs-source-dirs`) and this confuses the compiler. When compiling both tests and regular executables, GHC looks for `main` in a module named `Main`, and in this case that is `app/Main.hs` which does nothing, and your test module is compiled but not actually used.

- Don't put `app` in the `hs-source-dirs` of the test suite. And more generally, don't include a directory in more than one component (library, executable, test or benchmark suite), unless you know what you're doing. If you need to reuse code, you can put it in a library and have executable and test suite depend on it.
- The file that you put under `main-is:` in the `.cabal` file should include `module Main where` or no module line. The file name can be anything, but to avoid confusing it with a library module, it may be a good idea to use a lowercase name.

---

> If the module is not going to be imported by another module (Main, for example), then you are free to use any filename for it.
>
> --- https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/separate_compilation.html

Answer (score 2):

You're inconsistently trying to declare two different modules as `Main` - for the purpose of finding the `main` entry point you want `FindOddInt.hs` to be considered `Main`, but for the purpose of importing things you want `Main.hs` to be considered `Main`.

In your cabal file you have:

```
test-suite tests
    type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is: FindOddInt.hs
```

This says that the `Main` module *should* be in a file called `FindOddInt.hs` (in one of the `hs-source-dirs`). However in `FindOddInt.hs` itself you have:

```
module FindOddInt ( main ) where
import Main hiding ( main )
```

So there you're saying that that same file is not the `Main` module after all, it's `module FindOddInt`. And to make matters worse you're actually importing from *another* module called `Main` (which the compiler is going to have to find by the usual module to filename convention, so it'll look for a `Main.hs` file in any of the `hs-source-dirs`).

Apparently the way this ends up being compiled, the compiler ends up actually using the `Main.hs` file as the definition of the `Main` module, effectively overriding the `main-is: FindOddInt.hs` configuration in the cabal file. That means your test suite just runs `putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"` which of course succeeds. You can confirm this by running `cabal test --test-show-details=direct`, so that it shows the output from successful tests as well as failures. I get something like this:

```
Build profile: -w ghc-9.0.2 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - find-odd-int-0.1.0.0 (test:tests) (first run)
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for find-odd-int-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'tests' for find-odd-int-0.1.0.0..
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
Hello, Haskell!
Test suite tests: PASS
Test suite logged to:
/tmp/scratch/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.0.2/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0/t/tests/test/find-odd-int-0.1.0.0-tests.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

You can see the "Hello, Haskell" being printed there.

If you change your `FindOddInt.hs` file so that its header is `module Main` (since your cabal file says that is the `Main` module), then you get this error:

```
<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files: tests/FindOddInt.hs
                                                     tests/FindOddInt.hs
```

That's because your `other-modules: Main` is telling it to look for the `Main` module again. If you remove *that*, you get:

```
Building test suite 'tests' for find-odd-int-0.1.0.0..
Module imports form a cycle:
  module ‘Main’ (tests/FindOddInt.hs) imports itself
```

This is because the `import Main` is now being resolved against `FindOddInt.hs`, not `Main.hs`.

Basically, there is no way to make this work the way you seem to want it to. It is arguably a bug in Cabal and/or GHC that your original config compiles at all; it should possibly report an error about the mismatch between your cabal files's `main-is` and the referenced file's own decalared module name (and if not, it's extremely surprising that it uses *another* file as `Main` instead of that one). But no amount of fixing problems upstream is going to solve the fundamental contradiction in what you're trying to do. Either `FindOddInt.hs` is `Main` (in which case you can't import things from another `Main`), or it isn't.

In my experience, it is not really a good idea to ever import something from `Main`. A source file for `Main` can only really be included in a single application, so as soon as you want 2 application entry points (like your normal executable and a test suite), any code you want to share between them can't be in `Main`.

What this ends up meaning for my coding practices is that I only put very minimal code in `Main` that I don't intend to ever test with a library-level test suite (I might do further end-to-end testing of the whole binary, but that's different). Most of my code is typically in an internal library, so it can be imported by both my `Main` module and by my test suite; my actual `app` folder will usually only have a very thin `Main.hs` that stitches together a definition for `main` that is just combining imported things from the library (sometimes even it's just `main = SomeModule.realMain`, if I wanted run library tests on `realMain`).

I also agree with Li-yao Xia's recommendation that you don't put the same folder in the `hs-source-dirs` of multiple components. It's *possible* to do that sensibly (and is one option for giving your test suite access to modules that a library doesn't expose), but it also has drawbacks even when it doesn't cause errors like this one (mainly that you waste time compiling files multiple times for each component, instead of compiling once and then linking them). One folder per component is the simplest and easiest way to structure your project, unless you have a good reason otherwise.

For myself, I don't like giving `Main` a different name than `Main.hs`. You still can't have *another* `Main.hs` that is a different module, so I think it avoids confusion all round to stick firmly to the usual module naming convention and have the `Main.hs` filename be occupied by the `Main` module. You likely would have spotted what was happening if you had done that and tried to have a `Main.hs` importing from `Main` (and the compiler certainly would have spotted the two files claiming to be `Main`, as in an error I quoted above). There's not much additional safety in putting `Main` in a file with a name that can't be imported; it just enforces the "don't import from `Main`" rule that you end up having to stick to anyway. This makes `main-is: Main.hs` a pointless bit of boilerplate, but at least you don't have to think about it.