# cabal test is inconsistent with its QuickCheck log

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck

The following example fails (like it should) after 5 attempts:

```hs
prop_varName :: VarName -> Bool
prop_varName v = let s = content (getVarNameToken v) in
    length s <= 2 || isPrefixOf "a" s

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_varName
```

When I run `cabal test` I get an incorrect result (`PASS`)

```bash
$ cabal test # partially omitted for brevity ...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.8.1 -O1
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite dhscanner-ast-test: RUNNING...
Test suite dhscanner-ast-test: PASS
Test suite logged to:
dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0-dhscanner-ast-test.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

But when I check the log, everything is fine (counterexample found)

```bash
$ sed -n "1,3p" dhscanner-ast-0.1.0.0-dhscanner-ast-test.log
Test suite dhscanner-ast-test: RUNNING...
*** Failed! Falsified (after 5 tests):
VarName (Named {content = "U\SOH4@", location = ...})
```

**EDIT**: Here is the complete `cabal` file, though in hindsight,
it is not related to the actual problem.

```
cabal-version:      3.0
name:               dhscanner-ast
version:            0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
license:            GPL-3.0-only
license-file:       LICENSE
author:             ********
maintainer:         ***************@*****.com
-- copyright:
build-type:         Simple
extra-doc-files:    CHANGELOG.md
-- extra-source-files:

common warnings
    ghc-options: -Wall

library
    import:           warnings
    exposed-modules:
        Ast,
        Token,
        Location

    -- other-modules:
    -- other-extensions:
    build-depends:
        base ^>=4.19.0.0,
        containers,
        aeson

    hs-source-dirs: src

    default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite dhscanner-ast-test
    import:           warnings
    default-language: Haskell2010
    -- other-modules:
    -- other-extensions:
    type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:   test
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:
        base ^>=4.19.0.0,
        dhscanner-ast,
        QuickCheck,
        random
```

---

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723920/i-run-cabal-test-with-a-failing-case-but-it-always-passes)

Comment: *"Note: this is not a duplicate of this question"* please elaborate, like this the information is worthless.

Comment: @cafce25 sure - the non-testing part is *not* an executable (it's a library), and the file `Main.hs` does not exist in the repo other than the testing code.

Comment: Please show your .cabal file.

Comment: There's no error here, the `quickCheck` function only prints test results. You probably have this as a exit code test, and since your program exits successfully regardless of whether or not the property is satisfied it always passes. You'd have to use `quickCheckResult` to get the test result and fail on a failure, or even easier (but requires TH), just use `quickCheckAll`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I added the cabal file (as a link to a google doc to keep the actual post minimal)

Comment: @Cubic I made it work with `case of` - Is there a shorter way than asking the result of *every* test that runs ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom yes, `quickCheckAll` like I mentioned before. If you don't want to use TH you'll have to explicitly list the tests (but you don't need to match every test individually, you'd just fold over the results somehow).

Comment: Also, please do not link to important question details like the cabal config. Always include all relevant information within the text of the question.

Comment: @Cubic added cabal file as text

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual code that I ended up using:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
{
    result <- quickCheckResult prop_varName;
    case (isSuccess result) of
        True -> exitSuccess
        False -> exitFailure
}
```

Here is the output from `cabal test`:

```bash
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite dhscanner-ast-test: RUNNING...
*** Failed! Falsified (after 68 tests):
VarName (Named {content = "a\EOT{Z\\u3w+_", ... })
Test suite dhscanner-ast-test: FAIL
Test suite logged to: ...
```